# Wordpress Divi Theme loading page weird

Tags: wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I work with the latest version of Divi Theme and while the pages are loading (landscape responsive only) the page contents cover where the logo and navigation text is. I have removed all custom CSS content but without results.

Please see the attached images which are iPad screenshots. You can also see the content by visiting www.aditanase.com

I am not CSS proficient.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6lPt.jpg)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: seems its loading fine me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look to the header and sections media queries and set the margin-top or padding-top of the section (or content container) value according to the height of your header.

If you set your header with customizer panel, you can ajust height and css here. In fact, the customizer adds an inline style in the body tag : padding-top: (value of the height)

You can also find the class with the browser dev console and play with the value to find exactly what to do before modifying the css file. Search for `et-top-navigation` and `et-main-content`.

If you set or erase the value from the customizer, there's a chance that the value in the body tag disappears (for some other value it's like that), then the css media queries will be apply.

For example to set the section space between header and section, with small device

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 980px ) {
    .et_pb_section { padding: 50px 0 20px 0;}
    .et_pb_fullwidth_section { padding: 0; }
}
```

Hope it give some hints.